# Good practice when ajax and static page use same partialView?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When user comes on my site by url, controller generates `_Layout` + `partialView` inside.

Then when user walks by site, controller generates same `partialView` and sends by ajax.

Is there a good solution for this case?

*P.S.: My workaround:*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id, bool ajax = false)
    {
        var model = GetModelById(id);

        return ajax ? (ActionResult) PartialView(model) : View(model);
    }
}
```

*Where `/Home/Index/42` - for static page and `/Home/Index/42?ajax=true` - for ajax.*

Comment: `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` might be helpful to identify an xhr request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify ajax request:

```
var isAjax = Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

Or alternative in Asp.Net Core:

```
var isAjax = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
```